# How to enforce to run ZIO Tests sequentially

Tags: scala, integration-testing, zio, zio-test

I want to run two integration tests sequentially. How can this be achieved in *ZIO Test*?

Here is the Suite:

```
suite("Undeploy a Package")(
    testM("There is a Package") {
      PackageDeployer.deploy(pckg) *> // first deploy
        assertM(PackageUndeployer.undeploy(pckg), equalTo(StatusCode.NoContent))
    },
    testM(s"There is no Package") {
        assertM(PackageUndeployer.undeploy(pckg), equalTo(StatusCode.NotFound))
    })
```

*ZIO Test* runs the two tests in parallel. Is there a way to enforce that they are run in Sequence?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes! You can use `TestAspect.sequential` for that:

```scala
suite("Undeploy a Package")(
    testM("There is a Package") {
      PackageDeployer.deploy(pckg) *> // first deploy
        assertM(PackageUndeployer.undeploy(pckg), equalTo(StatusCode.NoContent))
    },
    testM(s"There is no Package") {
        assertM(PackageUndeployer.undeploy(pckg), equalTo(StatusCode.NotFound))
    }) @@ sequential
```